# Load Balancing of Support Calls

Tags: sql-server

I have been in and out of forums trying to figure out how I could accomplish Load balancing of Support calls per agent.

What I want to achieve is - Search for the agent with the least number of support calls each time, then from there assign the next support call to them so that the work is evenly distributed.

However, I simply have no clue on how to accomplish such load balancing algorithm. Could any of you SQL Server pro's guide me in the right direction please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had a table of active support calls and their current assignees, you could get the assignee with the lowest number of active support calls with the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Agent, COUNT(*) as Active_Calls
FROM Active_Calls
GROUP BY Agent
ORDER BY 2
```

That should return the agent with the lowest number of active calls, and the number of calls currently assigned to them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you - the above query works.
Would I then update the cases table to assign the next case coming in to the agent with the lowest number of calls?